# How to build a graph of connected components?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph

Suppose I have a matrix of chars (A, B, ...). I would like to find all contiguous "areas" filled with the same char and create a graph with vertices corresponding to those "areas". The graph vertices are connected if and only if the correspondent areas have a common border.

For example:

```
input matrix:
A A B C
A B B B
C C D D

areas:
1(A), 2(B), 3(C), 4(C), 5(D)

output graph (adjacency list):

1(A) - 2(B), 4(C)
2(B) - 1(A), 3(C), 4(C), 5(D)
3(C) - 2(B)
4(C) - 1(A), 2(B), 5(D)
5(D) - 2(B), 4(C)
```

My question is:  how to build such a graph given a matrix.

Obviously, I can do it as follows;

- run BFS/DFS to find the connected components ("areas")
- scan the matrix again to find the neighbors for each "area".

Is there any simpler and more efficient way to do that?

Comment: your approach seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that there is a much better solution.
Some optimisation would be possible converting characters to int.
But this would not change the effort in big O Notation.

Some might want to to store the info in bit fields to win a speed contest,
but this is not worth the effort, neither the code would be readable.